# What are the extra packages in standard that are not in minimal ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a VPS with a host that only allows installs of the minimal ubuntu image. I was wondering what other packages the standard ubuntu server 14.02 has that the minimal doesn't so that I can run the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Install "standard" in a VM. Run `dpkg -l` on both, then compare the two.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48886/how-do-i-list-the-default-installed-packages) on Ask Ubuntu and the answer seems to match what you're looking for. That said, the standard package list includes graphical desktop packages which you wouldn't want installed on a VPS, so use some discretion before installing lots of unneeded software.

To be honest, I'd just install missing packages as and when you need them.